# Disposing of CancellationTokenSource and its child CancellationTokenRegistration

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await, cancellationtokensource

Does `Dispose()` of `CancellationTokenSource` also dispose of any child `CancellationTokenRegistration` objects obtained via `Token.Register()`? Or must I individually dispose of each registration?

Example 1:

```
async Task GoAsync(CancellationToken ct1, CancellationToken ct2)
{
    using (var cts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(ct1, ct2))
    {
        cts.Token.Register(() => Debug.Print("cancelled"), false)
        await Task.Delay(1000, cts.Token);
    }
}
```

Example 2:

```
async Task GoAsync(CancellationToken ct1, CancellationToken ct2)
{
    using (var cts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(ct1, ct2))
    {
        using (cts.Token.Register(() => Debug.Print("cancelled"), false))
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000, cts.Token);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Contrary to what [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokenregistration.aspx) says, you don't dispose `CancellationTokenRegistration` to release resources, you do it to make the registration invalid. That is, you don't want the registered delegate to fire anymore, even if the token is canceled.

When you dispose the `CancellationTokenSource`, it means the associated token can't be canceled anymore. This means that you can be sure that the registered delegate won't fire, so there is no reason to dispose the registration in this case.